# JTable populated by ArrayList, bad result

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, tablemodel

I have to populate a `JTable` using `ArrayList` but when the table shows up it is filled with something else but the correct information. You can see how my table looks by clicking the next link.

[image: table]

`gui1` is the name of the main class, `theObject` is the name of the class that contains the structure of the information to be displayed on the  table.

Please help me with this issue !!

`ArrayList` definition:

```
 static ArrayList<theObject> datos = new ArrayList<theObject>();
```

This is code is for loading the ArrayList named "datos" :

try {                   // ------------------------ carga registros de proyectos ----------------------------

```
        contador = 0;
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((cadena1 = br.readLine()) != null){

            datos1 [0] = cadena1.substring(0,8);
            datos1 [1] = cadena1.substring(8,38);
            datos1 [2] = cadena1.substring(38,52);
            datos1 [3] = cadena1.substring(52,57);
            datos1 [4] = cadena1.substring(57,62);
            datos1 [5] = cadena1.substring(62,72);
            datos1 [6] = cadena1.substring(72,77);
            datos1 [7] = cadena1.substring(77,82);
            datos1 [8] = cadena1.substring(82,89);
            datos1 [9] = cadena1.substring(89,94);
            datos1 [10] = cadena1.substring(94,239);

            datos.add(new theObject(datos1));
            contador ++;


        }

        br.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The table is populated with this line:

```
tabla = new JTable(new MyModel(datos));
```

and now the classes involved in the code:

```
class theObject {
    String sap,cte,pep,dis1,dis2,norma,nvent,ntc,tmando,tparalel,equip;

    theObject(String dato[]) {
        this.sap = dato[0];
        this.cte = dato[1];
        this.pep = dato[2];
        this.dis1 = dato[3];
        this.dis2 = dato[4];
        this.norma = dato[5];
        this.nvent = dato[6];
        this.ntc = dato[7];
        this.tmando = dato[8];
        this.tparalel = dato[9];
        this.equip = dato[10];
    }

}

class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = { "FERT","CLIENTE ","PEP","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H" };

    ArrayList<theObject> arr1 = null;

    MyModel(ArrayList<theObject> arr1) {

        this.arr1 = arr1;
    }
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return pru2.datos.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        theObject a1 = datos.get(row);


        return a1;
    }
}
```

After compiling in Eclipse I got no errors, so I can´t identify the problem

Comment: We can't debug invisible code. Please post the code you are using to produce these results. One thing I see immediately is that you probably don't want things like `guiObject@4ab60e21`. That is just a matter of overriding the `toString` method of those objects.

Comment: @Aaron post your code

Comment: Sorry I've just added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `gui$theObject@4ab60e21` for every cell is because you are returning an entire `theObject` in the `getValueAt()`, which should only return a *field* of the `theObject` For example, your class looks like below

```
public class TheObject {   // please notice the Naming convention
                           // and follow it. Class begins with capital
    private fert;
    private cliente;
    private pep;
    // getter and setters
}
```

The your value in the `getValueAt()` should just return one of the fields based on the col. For example

```
private String[] columnNames = { "FERT","CLIENTE ","PEP" };
private ArrayList<TheObject> data;
...
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Object value = null;
    TheObject obj = data.get(row);
    switch(col) {
        case 0: value = obj.getFert(); break;
        case 1: value = obj.getCliente(); break;
        case 2: value = obj.getPep(); break;
        default: break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

So no your cell values will only be a field of the `TheObject` and not the entire `TheObject` object.

Comment: thanks a lot peeskillet your comments were correct, now mi table is working perfectly.